# Python - Correct way to get string without ANSI chars and also print pexpect data

Tags: python, string, pexpect

Currently, for these few days I have created a working code that works as I would expect, but there is one significant problem that I do not know how to solve.

But let's start from the beginning. I found something like pexpect and I wanted to use it on linux, instead of the usual "os.system". I'm going to use windscribe here...

```
def connect():
    username = "username1"
    while True:
        child = pexpect.spawn('windscribe account')
        match = child.expect("ee")
        rem = re.compile(r'(\x9B|x1B\[)[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')
        v = rem.sub('', str(child.before.decode('UTF-8')))
        sta = v.split("\n")
        for line in sta:
            if line.startswith("Username:"):
                user = line.replace('Username: ', '')
            if line.startswith("Data Usage:"):
                dataus = line.replace('Data Usage: ', '').replace('GB / 10 GB', '')
        print("The username is: ", username)
        print("Data used: ", dataus)
        if username == user:
           print("the same")
           if float(dataus) > 8:
              print("You used too much data!")
        else:
           print("not the same")
```

Unfortunately, when I try to display the currently logged in user, or check how much the limit has been used, theoretically everything works fine.
Displays:

```
The username is: username1
Data used: 7.79
**not the same**
```

But when I want to apply it in the program, i.e. compare:

`if float(dataus) > 8:`
I get an error that the string cannot be formatted to float and its preview is: "7.79 \x1b[0m\r"
Same with the username you want to compare in:

`if username == user:`

Theoretically they are the same, but not.

```
The username is: username1 \x1b[0m\r
Data used: 7.79 \x1b[0m\r
```

I temporarily got around this with this trick, but I don't quite understand why that code doesn't work if I decode it to utf-8 and I think I created a good regex

```
for line in sta:
            if line.startswith("Username:"):
                user = line.replace('Username: ', '').replace("\x1b[0m\r", '')
            if line.startswith("Data Usage:"):
                dataus = line.replace('Data Usage: ', '').replace('GB / 10 GB', '').replace("\x1b[0m\r", '')
```

**Question 2**
How i can print output from sent command? because now i must cut last two "ee" words, to print whole output ^^. Mean:

```
child = pexpect.spawn('windscribe account')
match = child.expect("ee")
rem = re.compile(r'(\x9B|x1B\[)[0-?]*[ -/]*[@-~]')
v = rem.sub('', str(child.before.decode('UTF-8')))
```

**Question 3**
Is pexpect is good for that usage? Or better way is use ex:

```
stdoutdata = subprocess.getoutput("windscribe status")
sta = stdoutdata.strip()
if "CONNECTED -- " in sta:
   ...
```

Comment: https://datagy.io/python-f-strings/  https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-f-strings-to-create-strings-in-python-3  https://www.pythonmorsels.com/string-formatting/

Comment: @toyotaSupra Could you expand on your answer? I know that I could use f-string instead of print, but I just wanted to visualize where the console shows login data and used transfer. Unfortunately, I do not know why the converted string, when comparing it, is added (meaning it is): ```\x1b[0m\r```. So the answer instead of correct comes out wrong because of this addition at the end of the string.

Comment: I was trying to chat with u. but u weren't online.

Comment: Can u print sta?

Comment: Btw, I may not be  un-valuable online because of long weekend.

Comment: Yeah sorry i was afk. :(
```print(f'{sta}')```
```['/x1b[30m\x1b[47m ------- My Account ------- \x1b[0m\r', Username: testuser\x1b[0m\r', 'Data Usage: 1.1 GB / 10 GB\x1b[0m\r', 'Plan: 30 GB Fr'] ``` - should be Fr - > Free but i dont know how to print all data without cut last two words. I also found that code on github, but i think this is similar code to my code: https://github.com/BergLucas/Python-Windscribe/blob/001e82ad1bbc7a5ba9222ef026563903183429d7/windscribe/windscribe.py#L710   and i dont know where is problem ;/ After ```.replace('GB / 10 GB', '')``` is:  ````1.1\x1b[0m\r```

Comment: I'm making a mistake somewhere. I can work around it with the above code (```.replace("\x1b[0m\r", '')```, but I would like to find the source of this problem so that I can know how it works in the future :)